# Timer function blocks HttpTrigger Azure function ap

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have 1 function app project, with a Timer trigger and a http trigger. (using DI or not, does not seem to matter)

The timertrigger:

```
public static class Timer
{
    [FunctionName("Timer")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup =true)]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

        Thread.Sleep(10000);//this is just for demonstrating the behavior!!

        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed done");
    }
}
```

the http trigger:

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("test2")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {

        return new OkObjectResult("Done");
    }
}
```

The issue is, that when the timer runs, all requests are blocked. Resulting in "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7071"

I read here and there (mostly in comments) that multiple triggers are (were) not supported, but that doesn't make sense to me as everything seems prepared for it anyway (i mean: i could not find any conclusive documentation about it, VS doesnt throw ANY resistance to add multiple, and even the debug interface and azure interface nicely sums up all the functions it could find...)

Is this behaviour expected, or is there some setting i can change to make it run in parallel or so??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be because of `RunOnStartup`. Any scheduled runs after the initial one do not have this issue.

However, if `RunOnStartup = false`, the trigger still might be called on startup and then it *does* have the issue.

As stated in the comments, `async` does not change anything (I actually use `async` and DI in the real scenario, but simplified the example here.)

Comment: "This turns out to be because of RunOnStartup. Any scheduled runs after the initial one do not have this issue."

Is there any documentation from Microsoft that documents this? Why is it only blocking the function process on startup and not later when the timered function is triggered. Also, is this only an issue for timered triggers?

Comment: Dont know about documentation (apart for 'Don't set runOnStartup to true in production.') or root cause. However it also seemed to be an issue for an initial run IF immediately ran, with runonstartup = false, so it might be some threading issue where it runs on the startup thread or whatever. Keep in mind as well this is a rather old post - havent tested it lately with newer SDK's.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is expected, since you're completely halting the Azure Functions process by running a `Thread.Sleep()`. As long as your Function App hasn't scaled to multiple instances, there's only one process running your Functions. This is where working asynchronously comes in.

If you change your timer triggered function to this, it should work fine.

```
[FunctionName("Timer")]
    public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup=true)] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

        await Task.Delay(10000);

        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed done");
    }
```

Next to this, please be advised:

- It is *not* recommended to have your timer triggered Function `RunOnStartup` set to `true`
- It is *not* advised to explicitly build in delays in Functions
- Multiple triggers for one Function are not supported, having multiple Functions each with their own trigger within one Function App *is* supported.
- A Function App is a collection of one or more Functions

> Triggers are what cause a function to run. A trigger defines how a function is invoked and a function must have exactly one trigger. Triggers have associated data, which is often provided as the payload of the function.

Source: [Azure Functions triggers and bindings concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings)

**EDIT:**
Tested it, and this also occurs when the Function is `async`, and also when it's running on Azure. This means the initial run of the Function with `runAtStartup=true` *always* blocks any other incoming requests, and with `runOnStartup` enabled the trigger is invoked whenever your function app is scaled.

Comment: Any delay in a trigger (of any sort) is usually the wrong approach and an X/Y problem 99.23423% of the time. Nice answer though

Comment: I know and I agree. I expect the question is an example and that they might have a different scenario where a method hogs the process. That needs to be made asynchronous. The answer is an example, too 

Comment: I agree thread.Sleep is wrong, but it was just to demonstrate the behavior.... Using async does NOT change anything. It does exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the clearification on trigger / function / function app.